# Unable to store Azure IoT message in database

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have an Azure Function which is triggered when my Azure IoT Hub receives a message. I can see in my function insights the function is triggered. I have put console logs to check. My connection is established with the database but then it goes to time out. Unable to debug the problem. Any help would be grateful. Consider me a newbie with Azure IoT as well as azure functions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add more information to your question? If possible it would be helpful to add some code from your Function.

Comment: Please provide more details and what is the exact error code? Take a look at the below documentations in case if you haven't checked earlier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-connectivity and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-connectivity